# How to wrap out IntPtr or ref IntPtr into HandleRef

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke, unmanaged

According to the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.handleref(v=vs.100).aspx), HandleRef can wrap a IntPtr to unmanaged resource.

```
HandleRef href = new HandleRef(obj, obj.unmanagedIntPtr);
```

I am wondering if I can wrap out IntPtr and ref IntPtr into HandleRef, because some of my pinvoke calls take out and/or ref.